# Unable to connect because your certificate is not yet valid. Check that your system time is correct

Tags: centos, openvpn

I do not know what I did wrong. My time is correct, I even updated it from Microsoft.

Client config:

```
tls-client
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
verb 3
reneg-sec 0
route-method exe
route-delay 2
ca ca.crt
auth-user-pass
```

Server config:

```
local xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
port 80
proto udp
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh1024.pem
plugin /usr/share/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
#status /etc/openvpn/logs/serverstatus-tcp.log
#log /etc/openvpn/logs/serverlog-tcp.log 
verb 3
float
duplicate-cn
#Limit server to a maximum of n concurrent clients.
max-clients 15
keepalive 20 300
```

Certificate

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=PH, ST=Benguet, L=Baguio City, O=company, OU=section, CN=skyflakes/name=none/emailAddress=none
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug  8 09:08:14 2011 GMT
            Not After : Aug  5 09:08:14 2021 GMT
        Subject: C=PH, ST=Benguet, L=Baguio City, O=company, OU=section, CN=server/name=none/emailAddress=none
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus (1024 bit):
                    00:cc:da:98:30:45:5b:45:1b:fb:19:dc:60:8a:07:
                    c1:f3:cd:0c:83:e2:a3:79:7a:5d:94:75:c9:7b:25:
                    30:36:c3:d9:51:f5:96:da:78:cf:d9:07:45:48:a6:
                    73:28:72:c4:bd:55:18:58:3e:f1:d4:a5:c3:1c:9b:
                    1c:22:c6:20:5e:c1:bb:14:d3:aa:f0:54:82:37:f6:
                    a1:47:75:75:a6:b4:a8:a7:d2:48:b8:f2:a0:ae:d0:
                    5d:1a:56:db:5e:b1:08:d9:d3:df:d5:56:ac:0b:0e:
                    39:0a:0c:6e:40:51:08:5e:c0:ae:32:85:a9:24:8f:
                    85:09:ff:72:16:26:e0:7e:cb
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            Netscape Cert Type:
                SSL Server
            Netscape Comment:
                Easy-RSA Generated Server Certificate
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                17:33:2D:C1:E5:F9:D0:AB:14:26:19:E5:C8:DC:BA:8E:D6:2C:81:01
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:AA:67:18:6E:E4:40:97:79:FC:52:78:ED:D1:30:C4:91:87:DC:24:58
                DirName:/C=PH/ST=Benguet/L=Baguio City/O=company/OU=section/CN=skyflakes/name=none/emailAddress=none
                serial:8E:66:F7:71:7B:7C:8E:78

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        7e:cb:b2:73:3a:16:50:1a:88:e3:ad:e3:07:89:03:03:7b:42:
        0f:67:52:29:67:31:c1:18:aa:70:5a:bc:cf:4a:40:4b:41:c2:
        1b:08:cc:03:a5:70:ac:2b:bd:86:fb:c0:ec:99:eb:fb:cc:fc:
        99:e4:ea:a2:c0:59:66:a0:c6:22:4e:3e:43:20:87:e2:4e:48:
        d9:f4:9b:8e:f1:4b:e1:f0:7d:55:d6:85:ad:d1:70:7d:59:42:
        58:d4:21:22:9b:51:09:bb:e0:e8:05:75:1a:4c:a9:1d:a3:57:
        fd:77:57:70:5b:4c:36:4f:99:73:c8:4d:eb:d3:5b:d1:38:ca:
        b0:d8
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEVTCCA76gAwIBAgIBATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBrzELMAkGA1UEBhMCUEgx
EDAOBgNVBAgTB0Jlbmd1ZXQxFDASBgNVBAcTC0JhZ3VpbyBDaXR5MRAwDgYDVQQK
Ewdjb21wYW55MRAwDgYDVQQLEwdzZWN0aW9uMRIwEAYDVQQDEwlza3lmbGFrZXMx
GTAXBgNVBCkTEEpvaG4gQ3lydXMgRGF2aWQxJTAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWFmFwYXRo
ZXRpYzAxMkBnbWFpbC5jb20wHhcNMTEwODA4MDkwODE0WhcNMjEwODA1MDkwODE0
WjCBrDELMAkGA1UEBhMCUEgxEDAOBgNVBAgTB0Jlbmd1ZXQxFDASBgNVBAcTC0Jh
Z3VpbyBDaXR5MRAwDgYDVQQKEwdjb21wYW55MRAwDgYDVQQLEwdzZWN0aW9uMQ8w
DQYDVQQDEwZzZXJ2ZXIxGTAXBgNVBCkTEEpvaG4gQ3lydXMgRGF2aWQxJTAjBgkq
hkiG9w0BCQEWFmFwYXRoZXRpYzAxMkBnbWFpbC5jb20wgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEB
BQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAMzamDBFW0Ub+xncYIoHwfPNDIPio3l6XZR1yXslMDbD2VH1
ltp4z9kHRUimcyhyxL1VGFg+8dSlwxybHCLGIF7BuxTTqvBUgjf2oUd1daa0qKfS
SLjyoK7QXRpW216xCNnT39VWrAsOOQoMbkBRCF7ArjKFqSSPhQn/chYm4H7LAgMB
AAGjggGAMIIBfDAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMBEGCWCGSAGG+EIBAQQEAwIGQDA0BglghkgB
hvhCAQ0EJxYlRWFzeS1SU0EgR2VuZXJhdGVkIFNlcnZlciBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZTAd
BgNVHQ4EFgQUFzMtweX50KsUJhnlyNy6jtYsgQEwgeQGA1UdIwSB3DCB2YAUqmcY
buRAl3n8Unjt0TDEkYfcJFihgbWkgbIwga8xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlBIMRAwDgYDVQQI
EwdCZW5ndWV0MRQwEgYDVQQHEwtCYWd1aW8gQ2l0eTEQMA4GA1UEChMHY29tcGFu
eTEQMA4GA1UECxMHc2VjdGlvbjESMBAGA1UEAxMJc2t5Zmxha2VzMRkwFwYDVQQp
ExBKb2huIEN5cnVzIERhdmlkMSUwIwYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhZhcGF0aGV0aWMwMTJA
Z21haWwuY29tggkAjmb3cXt8jngwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwEwCwYDVR0P
BAQDAgWgMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBAH7LsnM6FlAaiOOt4weJAwN7Qg9nUiln
McEYqnBavM9KQEtBwhsIzAOlcKwrvYb7wOyZ6/vM/Jnk6qLAWWagxiJOPkMgh+JO
SNn0m47xS+HwfVXWha3RcH1ZQljUISKbUQm74OgFdRpMqR2jV/13V3BbTDZPmXPI
TevTW9E4yrDY
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Well, what's the validity period of the certificate?  The server might be the one with the wrong time.

Comment: i don't know :(

Comment: `openssl x509 -in /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt -text` - the "Validity" section.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reading your question at 0939BST on 08.08.2011, which is 0839GMT 08.08.2011, and it says you wrote the question some 9 hours ago.  That certificate says its validity is "Not Before: Aug  8 09:08:14 2011 GMT", so it's not going to be valid for another 29 minutes yet, and it wasn't yet valid when you wrote the question.  Wait half an hour and try again; it's perfectly possible that everybody's clocks are correct, and that the error message means exactly what it says!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too... Check and update the date/time on both client and server. In my case the server clock was NOT correct when the certificate was created. You may either wait until the certificate become valid -- OR -- correct the clock (date and time) on server, then DELETE old certificates and RE-ISSUE all certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the time reads correct, verify that the time-zone is correct.  I've had this bite me in the past (though not when using NTP) and it is pretty easy to correct if you have a time source.  On Ubuntu the tool to change the time-zone system-wide is tzselect, and you can edit the display time zone on a short-term or personal basis using the TZ environment variable.

To display the current time zone:   date +%Z

The system time zone:  cat /etc/timezone